# Using light slider with angular4

Tags: jquery, html, angular

Hi I am using [lightslider](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lightslider) with Angular4 but in that I am facing issue in initialization in `lightslider()`. When I initialize light slider on any html element in index.html, it works but when I navigate to the page in which slider should be initialize it fails. For Example,

`Home.html` template and `Home.ts` component are the main and first page of my application and there is slider on `sliderHome` element and another page is `Info.html`template and `Info.ts` component, which has slier on `inforSlider` element. So when user lands on first page that is `Home` page, slider is working but when user navigate from this page to `Info` page slider is not working as it should be and it is because, it is not initialized. How can I initialize it when particular component loads.

The code is like below and it is put in `index.html` page(main page),

```
$(document).ready(function () {
setTimeout(function () {
  $('#sliderHome').lightSlider({
    adaptiveHeight: true,
    item: 1,
    slideMargin: 0,
    loop: true
  });
  $('#inforSlider').lightSlider({
    adaptiveHeight: true,
    item: 1,
    slideMargin: 0,
    loop: true
  });
}, 500);
});
```

Comment: Post a code. Some narative about something that's not working isn't really useful

Comment: @tchelidze I updated the code and I think the issue is with app is first loaded it can find only sliderHome element as inforSlider element is not loaded at that time and when user navigate to info page element is there but script will not execute at that time.

Comment: Yes, that sounds correct, so you may move initialization for `inforSlider` to corresponding html.

Comment: @tchelidze Can post some code or link for the code so I get reference from there? I tried with initialize it in component in ngAfterViewInit method but it throw error like lightSlider is not a method even if slider JS is also loaded on page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed this using following code, I have put this code in the component where slider needs to be initialized.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Renderer2, Inject } from "@angular/core";
import { DOCUMENT } from "@angular/platform-browser";

@Component({
selector: 'slider-selector',
templateUrl: './slider.html',
styleUrls: ['./slider.css']
})
export class CustomeComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(
    private _renderer2: Renderer2,
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private _document
) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
    let script = this._renderer2.createElement('script');
    script.type = `text/javascript`;
    script.text = `
        {
            $(document).ready(function () {
                setTimeout(function(){
                     $('#inforSlider').lightSlider({
                        adaptiveHeight: true,
                        item: 1,
                        slideMargin: 0,
                        loop: true
                      });
                },500);
            });
        }
    `;
    this._renderer2.appendChild(this._document.body, script);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "ngAfterViewInit" lifecycle hook, through importing AfterViewInit. [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit)  You can use it as shown below:

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.doJqueryLoad();     
    this.doClassicLoad();

    $(this.el.nativeElement)
        .chosen()
        .on('change', (e, args) => {
            this.selectedValue = args.selected;
        });
}

doClassicLoad() {
  // A $( document ).ready() block.
  $( document ).ready(function() {
      console.log( "Unnecessary..." );
  });      
}

// You don't need to use document.ready... 
doJqueryLoad() {
    console.log("Can use jquery without doing document.ready")
    var testDivCount = $('#testDiv').length;
    console.log("TestDivCount: ", testDivCount);
}
```