# Can we use jQuery LightSlider in Angular 7?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular

I have done LightSlider with angular js before, but I'm not sure I can use it in angular 7. I've been doing research for several times but it's seem like no example or any codepen have done it. I have tried to do it but it doesn't work. So I came here to ask you guys. Can I use Light slider with angular 7.
This is [LightSlider](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lightslider)

Comment: Can and should are two different questions, you can use any jQuery plugins with Angular, but you shouldn't use any. jQuery was great in it's day but that day has well and truly past. You shouldn't include jQuery in an Angular project. Look for a carousel component for Angular.

Comment: That being said you must not have searched very hard as there are multiple examples of how to including this StackOverflow answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48475934/using-light-slider-with-angular4

Comment: @adrian-brand Using carousel you can't swipe over to change the slide.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to. First, make sure you npm-install both jQuery and LightSlider and add them to the minimized styles and scripts collection of the angular.json file (architect/build/options):

```
{
  ...
  "projects": {
    "testLightSlider": {
      ...
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "options": {
            ...,
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/lightslider/dist/css/lightslider.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/lightslider/dist/js/lightslider.min.js"
            ]
          }
          ...
```

Then simply do `declare var $` right below the imports in the component you want to use LightSlider and use jQuery to initialize it. Just remember using jQuery inside OnInit or AfterViewInit, you'll have wait for the component template to be ready (jQuery needs the DOM ready)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
declare var $: any;

@Component({...})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    $('#target').lightSlider({
      // options here...
    });
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It's quite complicated I have done npm both of them but still doesn't work. It's show like the normal list.